# Fill progress to the right of thumb

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I want to be able to fill the area to the right without it affecting my fill to the left of the thumb

[image]

**My progress XML**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <size android:height="90dp"/>
                <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#00ef3c"/>
                <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/background">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <size android:height="90dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#bd767676" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Custom seekbar style**

```
<style name="SeekbarCustom">
    <item name="android:indeterminate">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/video_seek_bar_progress</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/video_seek_bar_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">8px</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally solved it. Dont know if it is the best solution. But it will do

What i did is that i let the `SecondaryProgress` attribute act has the filler. Then i set its gravity to start from the right side. Then i just created a listener to change its progress.

**The listener**

```
binding.fragmentPostVideoSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
    int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
    seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(100 - progress);
  }
});
```

**XML drawable**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <size android:height="90dp"/>
                <stroke
                  android:width="2dp"
                  android:color="#00ef3c"/>
                <solid android:color="#00ffffff"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip android:gravity="right">
            <shape>
                <size android:height="90dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#b7797979"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```